# Can you set-up Salesforce to Salesforce if both orgs are on Professional Edition?

Tags: professional-edition, salesforce-to-salesforce

Both parties are currently using PE

Answer (score 0):

I have never tried to do this but according to https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=business_network_intro.htm the feature is available in PE.